# How can I convert an IEEE-754 binary representation String to a float or double in Java?

Tags: java, string, floating-point, ieee-754, string-parsing

Since all Java floating-point numbers, which are *floats* and *doubles*, are internally represented as bits, I want to find an *efficient* algorithm to convert a String representing the bits of that *float* or *double* and convert it into its corresponding *floating-point number* - I couldn't find a built-in library function for it so I resorted to writing it by myself.

A binary String of length 32 represents a *float*, where as a binary String of length 64 will be converted to a *double*. All *floats* can be converted to *doubles* without loss of accuracy. Spaces are ignored.

**Examples**

- `"0 10000000 10010010000111111011011"` becomes `3.141592` as a *float*.
- `"1 11111111 00000000000000000000000"` becomes `-infinity`.
- `"0 11111111 10010010000111111011011"` becomes a *float* `NaN`.
- `"1 10000000000 0101101111110000101010001011000101000101011101101001"`
  becomes a *double* value closest to *-e*, which is `2.71828182845904509079559829843`

**So far I have this mass of a code:**

```
public static double ieee(String binString) throws Exception {
    binString = binString.replace(" ", "");
    if (binString.length() == 32) {
        String exponentB = binString.substring(1, 9);
        String mantissaB = binString.substring(9, 32);
        int sgn = binString.charAt(0) == '0' ? 1 : -1;
        int exponent = Integer.parseInt(exponentB, 2) - 127; // Biased by 127
        double mantissa = 1 + Integer.parseInt(mantissaB, 2) / Math.pow(2, 23);

        if (exponent == 128 && mantissa == 1)
            return sgn == 1 ? Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY : Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        if (exponent == 128 && mantissa != 0)
            return Double.NaN;
        if (exponent == -127)
            return sgn*Math.pow(2,-126)*(mantissa - 1);
        return sgn*Math.pow(2, exponent)*mantissa;
    }
    else if (binString.length() == 64) {
        String exponentB = binString.substring(1, 12);
        String mantissaB = binString.substring(12, 64);
        int sgn = binString.charAt(0) == '0' ? 1 : -1;
        int exponent = Integer.parseInt(exponentB, 2) - 1023; // Biased by 1023
        double mantissa = 1 + Long.parseLong(mantissaB, 2) / Math.pow(2, 52);

        if (exponent == 1024 && mantissa == 1)
            return sgn == 1 ? Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY : Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        if (exponent == 1024 && mantissa != 0)
            return Double.NaN;
        if (exponent == -1023)
            return sgn*Math.pow(2,-1022)*(mantissa - 1);
        return sgn*Math.pow(2, exponent)*mantissa;
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Does not represent internal bits of a floating-point number");
    }
}
```

Though my code works as of now, what is the neatest or fastest method to convert a IEEE-754 binary representation String to its `float` or `double`, in terms of speed and amount of code? The most efficient method with a good explanation of its efficiency and expertise is preferred.

Comment: This question is **not** about converting a "binary" decimal into a float.

Comment: If you're looking to improve code that already works, you should probably try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @StephenC how about the case for doubles? Is the simplified code more efficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This approach is probably more efficient.  It is certainly simpler and more maintainable.

1. Remove spaces from string
2. Validate string length ...
3. Convert binary string to `int`
4. Call `Float.intBitsToFloat(int)` to convert to an `float`.

For doubles, use `long` and the equivalent `Double` method.

---

> Is the simplified code more efficient?

The only way to be sure is to benchmark it.  But based on what your code is doing, I *believe* so.

Comment: When benchmarking, is the your method definitely faster? My "inefficient-looking" algorithm looks like a "more naive" approach to convert an ieee754 float representation.

Comment: 1) Feel free to write your own benchmark :-)  2) Yes.  My approach avoids all of that messy stuff.  Under the hood `intBitsToFloat` will be a simple assignment.

Answer (score 1):

**From @StephenC**, the improved code to convert the IEEE-754 binary representation to its corresponding floating-point value takes up just one line:

```
return Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(binString, 2));
```

- `Integer.parseUnsignedInt(binString, 2)` converts the *unsigned* int in binary digits from range 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1 to the `int` representation. The `parseInt(...)` does not work because `parseInt` involves an explicit sign in its `binString`, and if it represents a negative int, a leading hyphen is required instead of a value that is 2<sup>31</sup> or greater. Similarly, `Long.parseUnsignedLong(binString, 2)` appiles for the 64-bit case.
- `Float.intBitsToFloat(int n)` represents the float value with the same bits internally stored as the int value `n`. Similarly, `Double.longBitsToDouble(long n)` works for the 64-bit case.
- Using "method composition", this line first converts the (unsigned) binary string into its corresponding int, and then converts it into the floating-point value with the same stored bits.

**The final code would be**

```
public static double ieeeToFloat(String binString) throws Exception {
    binString = binString.replace(" ", "");
    /* 32-bit */
    if (binString.length() == 32) {
        return Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(binString, 2));
    }
    /* 64-bit */
    else if (binString.length() == 64) {
        return Double.longBitsToDouble(Long.parseUnsignedLong(binString, 2));
    }
    /* An exception thrown for mismatched strings */
    else {
        throw new Exception("Does not represent internal bits of a floating-point number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class IEEE754ToFloatingValues {

public static double convertToInt(String mantissa_str) {
    
    int power_count = -1;
    double mantissa_int = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mantissa_str.length(); i++) {
        // System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(mantissa_str.charAt(i) + ""));
        mantissa_int += (Integer.parseInt(mantissa_str.charAt(i) + "") * Math.pow(2, power_count));
        power_count -= 1;
    }
    return mantissa_int + 1.0;
}

public static String convertToBinary(int i) {
    
    return Integer.toBinaryString(i + 0b10000).substring(1);
}

public static String decimalToHex(String decimal) {

    int i = Integer.parseInt(decimal);
    System.out.println("<<>>" + i);
    String my_hexdata = Integer.toHexString(i);

    System.out.println(my_hexdata);

    return String.valueOf(ReturnFloatingValue(my_hexdata));

}

public static double ReturnFloatingValue(String my_hexdata) {

    String myString = "";
    if (my_hexdata == null) {
        return -2.0;
    }
    if (my_hexdata.length() != 8) {
        myString = String.format("%1$-" + 8 + "s", my_hexdata).replace(' ', '0');

        System.out.println("My hex data after appending 0's is : " + myString);
    }

    String binary = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(myString.charAt(i) + "", 16);
        binary += convertToBinary(num);
    }

    System.out.println("Binary length is :  " + binary.length());

    System.out.println("Binary number is : " + binary);
    if (binary == null || binary.isEmpty()) {
        return -3.0;
    }
    String ieee_32 = binary.substring(2);

    ieee_32 = String.format("%1$-32s", binary).replace(' ', '0');

    long sign_bit = Long.parseLong(new StringBuilder().append(ieee_32.charAt(0)).toString());

    long exponent_bias = Long.parseLong(ieee_32.substring(1, 9), 2);
    long exponent_unbias = exponent_bias - 127L;

    System.out.println("Exponent unbias is  : " + exponent_unbias);
    String mantissa_str = ieee_32.substring(9);
    double mantissa_int = convertToInt(mantissa_str);
    double real_no = Math.pow(-1.0, (double) sign_bit) * mantissa_int * Math.pow(2.0, (double) exponent_unbias);

    System.out.println("Real no is : " + real_no);
    return real_no;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //decimalToHex("16547");
}

}
```

Comment: We appreciate code but not code-only answers. Please explain your logic/approach.